# AngularJS : ng-show complex conditions problems with IE9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

The below code already works in all the browsers including IE10. It has problems only in IE9. So I am guessing there is no syntax error or logic error in code, may be I just need a different way to write the condition in `ng-show`

```
   <div class="control-group" ng-show="!waste.id" style="display:inline-block">
      <label class="control-label" for="shipments">Treatment or Shipment Frequency</label>
      <div class="controls controls-row">
        <div>
          <input type="number" id="shipments" name="shipments" maxlength="50" ng-required="!waste.id && !noChange" ng-model="waste.shipments" ng-disabled="noChange" placeholder="Shipment" class="input-small" step="any">
          <i class="inline icon-info-sign" ng-show="form.shipments.$invalid || form.shipments.$error.required == true"></i>
          <span class="help-inline">times per</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="number" id="frequency" name="frequency" maxlength="50" ng-required="!waste.id && !noChange" ng-model="waste.frequency" ng-disabled="noChange" placeholder="Frequency" class="input-small" step="any">
          <i class="inline icon-info-sign" ng-show="form.frequency.$error.required == true || form.frequency.$invalid"></i>
          <span class="help-inline">year(s)</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see "Treatment and Shipment Frequency" is a number and is valid when entered value is number and required == true. The conditions when I try to evaluate differently, I came to know that the expression with `$invalid` won't work meaning `type=number` and `$invalid` might have some problem in IE9 and that's why `<i>` tag won't go away. This is happening only in IE9. Can someone help me